# Call a :scope method for sum of has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have some model classes.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  ...
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :free, -> {where('price == ?', 0)}
end
```

Canonical usage

```
free_products = user.products.free
```

But I want the following behavior:

```
users = User.where(...)
all_free_products = users.flat_map(&:products).free
```

I want to apply a scope method to sum of has_many associations. As expected, it raises the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `free' for #<Array:0x00123456abcdef>
```

Is there an easy way to define all `scope` methods for the `Array` result of `user.flat_map(&:products)` ?

Comment: Why are you using `flat_map`?

Comment: flat_map() = map().flatten

Because the initial result is Array of Arrays, and I convert it to Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare the `belongs_to :user` association in the products model so you can use `merge`

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :free, -> { where(price: 0) }
end

users = User.where(...)
products = Project.joins(:user).merge(users).free
```